# Finding Expected Value of Game based on rolling die

Tags: expected-value, game-theory

There are two people playing a game. Each player has a fair 6 sided die. The first player to get 20 points within 10 rounds wins. The player with the higher roll gains the difference in points for that round. For example, I roll a 5 and you roll a 3, I gain 2 points that round. (Rolling same number is no points gained or lost | Game ends if no one gets 20 points in 10 rounds) Given this information, what is the expected number of points gained per round by the winning player?

I tried approaching this multiple ways. Calculating expected value of winning in 4 rounds, 5 rounds, etc, but it seemed to be many calculations. I then tried an approach mapping the probabilities of points gained/lost each round but could not seem to get anywhere. Is there an efficient way to solve this problem?

Comment: You may need to program a recursion finding $p(y,m,r)$ as the probability your score is $y$ and my score $m$ after $r$ rounds, starting with $p(0,0,0)=1$

Comment: @Henry Unsure whether you are shaping your response to the inferred background of the OP (i.e. original poster).  I am totally ignorant of *Markov Chains*.  Given that, I have seen similar MathSE problems that succumb to recursion that also succumb (perhaps in a more formal manner) to Markov Chains.  Will Markov Chains work here?

Comment: @user2661923 with a suitable definition of states (there are a lot of them) and a suitable transition matrix (raised to the $10$th power), yes you could treat this as a Markov chain

Comment: struggling with exactly same problem, done a simulation and get around 2.29 points per round for the winning player. Is this similar to what you get?